# RouteValueDictionary values changing from strings to arrays on POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `RouteValueDictionary` that is attached to an object being passed to a view. This object contains an array of other objects called SelectedItems that is used to populate a grid with check boxes that a user can select. Since this object is then passed back to the controller and routed differently depending on how the user interacts with the UI, it also contains a `RouteValueDictionary` called ReturnValues. The basic setup of the class looks more or less like this:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class ItemSelection
{
    public object[] SelectedItems { get; set; }
    public RouteValueDictionary ReturnValues { get; set; }

    public ItemSelection()
    {
        ReturnValues = new RouteValueDictionary()
        {
            { "key1", "routeValue1" },
            { "key2", "routeValue2" },
            { "key3", "routeValue3" }
        }
    }
}
```

This would have worked perfectly, except the ReturnValues property was coming back "null" in the POST

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850169/mvc3-hiddenfor-dictionary-values) regarding the mapping of dictionaries, I came up with the following solution on the view:

```cs
<%
    foreach(var key in Model.Keys)
    {
        Html.Render(Html.HiddenFor(m => m[key]));
    }
%>
```

This renders a bunch of hidden inputs to the html that look like this for each item:

```html
<input id="ReturnValues__key1_" name="ReturnValues.[key1]" type="hidden" value="routeValue1">
```

I have also tried something similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358075/model-binding-a-dictionary):

```cs
<%
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        Html.Hidden("ReturnValues[" + i + "].Key", Model.ElementAt(i).Key);
        Html.Hidden("ReturnValues[" + i + "].Value", Model.ElementAt(i).Value);
    }
%>
```

Which renders this:

```html
<input id="ReturnValues_ReturnValues_0__Key" name="ReturnValues.ReturnValues[0].Key" type="hidden" value="key1">
<input id="ReturnValues_ReturnValues_0__Value" name="ReturnValues.ReturnValues[0].Value" type="hidden" value="routeValue1">
```

Both of these work somewhat, except when the `RouteValueDictionary` gets posted back to the controller, the `Values` property goes from being a collection of `Strings` to a collection of `String[1]` (i.e., the strings become arrays). So, drawn out, the dictionary entries go from looking like this:

```cs
{ "key1", "routeValue1" }
```

To this:

```cs
{ "key1", { "routeValue1" } }
```

I've toyed around with it for hours, but I cannot seem to find out what the issue is. Since the code in my controller is routing to the `ToString()` of the associated value, my full route ends up looking like `/area/controller/System.String[]/`

Is there something I'm missing when mapping my `RouteValueDictionary` to hidden fields?

**UPDATE:** I ended up making a custom model binder for `RouteValueDictionary` objects. (see answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a custom model binder for `RouteValueDictionary` objects. Here are the relevant methods:

```
public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
{
    if (bindingContext.ValueProvider.ContainsPrefix(bindingContext.ModelName))
    {
        RouteValueDictionary baseModel = (bindingContext.Model as RouteValueDictionary) ?? (base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) as RouteValueDictionary);

        if (baseModel != null)
        {    // start off with a direct copy of the bound model            
            var returnModel = new RouteValueDictionary();
            baseModel.ForEach(x => returnModel[x.Key] = item.Value);

            // Sometimes the DefaultModelBinder turns the RouteValueDictionary.Values property into a collection of single-item arrays. This resets them to the correct values.
            foreach (var key in baseModel.Keys)
            {
                returnModel[key] = GetValue(bindingContext, key); // GetValue method body below                        
            }

            return returnModel;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private object GetValue(ModelBindingContext context, string key)
{
    var name = String.Format("{0}[{1}]", String.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ModelName) ? String.Empty : context.ModelName, key);
    var attemptedResult = context.ValueProvider.GetValue(name);

    if (attemptedResult != null && attemptedResult.AttemptedValue != null)
    {
        return attemptedResult.AttemptedValue;        
    }

    return null;
}
```